# Python Selenium use list of Urls

Tags: python, selenium

I have a text list of urls named all_urls.txt. Each url in the text file is on a single line. I want to pass this list to selenium (python) to extract specific data. I can achieve this by using the url's one by one but this is not efficient. My code at present looks like this:-

```
profile = FirefoxProfile('/home/test/.mozilla/firefox/mfgrtrtr.Default3')
browser = webdriver.Firefox(firefox_profile=profile)
browser.maximize_window()
# get website
browser.get('https://www.some-website.com/')
# get current url
print browser.current_url
# get name & get phone number
name = browser.find_element_by_class_name("name")
print name.text
phone = browser.find_element_by_class_name("phone")
print phone.text
```

How can I pass the list to browser.get and extract name and phone from each url. Thanks in advance for your help, I am new to python but enjoying the challenge.

Comment: Do you know how to open a file and  use a for loop? `with open(yourfile) as f:for url in map(str.rstrip, f) ...`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You probably need a `for` loop, which can iterate over a list. Your code should look something like this:

```
profile = FirefoxProfile('/home/test/.mozilla/firefox/mfgrtrtr.Default3')
browser = webdriver.Firefox(firefox_profile=profile)
browser.maximize_window()
with open("your_file_name") as in_file:
    for url in in_file:
        # get website
        browser.get(url.strip())
        # get current url
        print browser.current_url
        # get name & get phone number
        name = browser.find_element_by_class_name("name")
        print name.text
        phone = browser.find_element_by_class_name("phone")
        print phone.text
```

The `.strip` method call on the URL simply ensures that it has no leading or trailing whitespace - lines read in from a file normally include the trailing newline character.

Answer (score 2):

Open the file:

```
my_file = open("all_urls.txt", "r")
```

Iterate throught it and use the `get` function on each url:

```
for url in my_file:
    browser.get(url)
    print ...
    print ...
```